# I'm not 100% sure how I should construct the punctuation for a sentence.

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I'm having one of those mornings where nothing seems quite right so would appreciate some input

(... blah)" is highly inadvisable, but, these things happen."

Comment: I guess I'm basically asking if its acceptable common usage to use the comma after 'but' to effect a slight pregnant pause without using '...' or if i should just get rid of it altogether

Comment: If you want to add a pause, the ellipsis would be best. The double comma is a very awkward construction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have an ellipsis earlier in the paragraph so don't want to overload it, I was trying to give it a small break without as much emphasis but i think I'll just drop it. Thanks again, I just kept staring at it!

Comment: would a dash be better?

Comment: " is highly inadvisable-but these things happen."

Comment: Not following a comma and conjunction. If the pause is really necessary, perhaps breaking it into separate sentences would be better?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not a dash can be used interchangeably with a comma when connecting sentences

Comment: I don't think you ***ever*** need a comma both before and after *but*. Do people ever pause in speech both before and after *but*? I don't think replacing the second comma with an ellipsis helps, either. I might drop the comma before in this case, although this isn't concordant with most style handbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a coordinating conjunction, only one comma is used.

> I went to the store, and I bought some milk.
>
> We could go to the store, or we could to the mall.
>
> "Blank is highly inadvisable, but these things happen.

For more information, this is a pretty good webpage on coordinating conjunctions: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/coordinatingconjunction.htm